# Typescript: import not working, but including script on page works

Tags: typescript, webpack, import

I'm trying to use the d3-cloud library in Typescript: https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud

I included it the following ways:

**FAILS:**

```
import * as d3 from 'd3-cloud/build/d3.layout.cloud.js'
declare let d3: any;
```

Note: d3.layout.cloud.js is standalone version of this library.

However when I load the app. it throws: **ERROR ReferenceError: d3 is not defined**.

---

When I include the same library with a script tag, it "works" (still some other errors but d3 is defined).

**WORKS:**

```
 <script src="../node_modules/d3-cloud/build/d3.layout.cloud.js"></script>
```

---

I googled how to import such libraries, but from what I found, this is the way to include it. I see that, the library is loaded in Chrome, but breakpoints inside the library are never called.

I noticed, that the module has this wrapper:

```
(function(f) {
    if (typeof exports === "object" && typeof module !== "undefined") {
        module.exports = f()
    } else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define([], f)
    } else { ...
    }
}
)(function() { .. });
```

I assume, this has something to do with a module loader too. However, the inside is never called.

Do I have to call it somehow manually? Can I call it at all?

Comment: Have you checked the network traffic to make sure the urls are correct?  I only ask because I looked at https://www.jasondavies.com/wordcloud/ and they seem to be including the files directly also, and the d3 is defined on the window object in that example.

Comment: Yes, I can see that the library is included in the bundle and I can find it's code in the browser. It just doesn't get called... (Also added debugger in the beginning of the file, it was hit)

Comment: What module loader are you using?  AMD, ECMAScript 2015, none?  It looks like the wrapper you mention in d3.layout.cloud.js is a UMD wrapper (https://github.com/umdjs/umd).  If you include the file via a script tag, I do not see how this can fail to be called.